# On link click redirect after cookie is set with PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a page which has two links. When you click one of the link than the PHP should redirect you to the clicked page and when you visit back the cookie should remember your previous choice and it should load the specific page and not the page with the two links.
I was able to set the cookie but I don't know how to use it when I click on the links.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
    $cookie_name = 'redirect';
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
        setcookie($cookie_name , 'redirect-link', time()+(60*60*24*365), "/"); 
    } 

    else {
        print 'Cookie with name ' . $cookie_name. ' value is: ' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<br/>
<a href="https://link1.com">link1</a>
<a href="https://link2.com">link2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

main page

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['thechoosenone'])
{
     $url='<baseusl>/'.($_COOKIE['thechoosenone'];
     header('Location: '.$url);
}
```

on the linked page eg:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['thechoosenone'])) {
//create cockie $_COOKIE['thechoosenone'] and asight the url
}else{
   $url='<baseusl>/'.($_COOKIE['thechoosenone'];
   header('Location: '.$url);
   //stop choosing via manual url browsing 
}
```

Comment: your answer is useful but I don't understand how can I store the choosen click in the cookie. And I need to have the code just on main page.

Comment: you will need to use maltiple pages anyway 
there are only 3 ways 

1) is ajax and having the cookie genaration on a new page 

2 )is having the code on the linked page

3) create cookies from js